# Event not trigger in magento api sales_order_invoice.create

Tags: api, magento

I am using SOAP V1 api

```
$parameters = array('orderIncrementId' => $postdata['order_id'], $items);

$createInvoice = $proxy->call($sessionId,'sales_order_invoice.create', $parameters);
```

Can someone please help me, how to trigger invoice event(sales_order_invoice_pay) when invoice from api.

Answer (score 0):

Create custom event after create invoice from API.

```
$baseUrl = 'http://example.com/index.php/';

$proxy = new SoapClient($baseUrl.'api/soap/?wsdl');

$createInvoice = $proxy->call($sessionId,'sales_order_invoice.create', $parameters);

$orderinvoice = Mage::getModel('sales/order_invoice')->loadByIncrementId($createInvoice);

Mage::dispatchEvent('sales_order_invoice_pay_api', array('invoice'=>$orderinvoice));
```

Add event trigger in module config.xml file

```
<config>
    <global>
     ..........
     ..........
      <events>
           <sales_order_invoice_pay_api>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_modulename_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>setinvoicestatetaxapi</method>
                    </namespace_modulename_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_invoice_pay_api>
      </events>
     ..........
     ..........
   <global>
<config>
```

Create / modify Observer.php

```
<?php

class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer extends Varien_Object
{
...............
...............

public function setinvoicestatetaxapi(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
  $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice();
}

...............
...............
}
```